# Is there any way using script to delete some stuff in a google doc after google forms fills spreadsheet data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a google doc that I'm using as a template, and it will be filled with the results of google forms data (which populates in a spreadsheet). The user will be checking off items on various lists on the form, and those items will get transferred over to the google doc template. On the doc template I want the script to be able to delete the header/initial bullet point space/blank space associated with any sections that don't end up having any items checked off, just to clean things up.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about doing it or what kinds of terms should I be googling to figure it out?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: As far as research goes, I see two possible paths forward: 1) Figure out if Google provides an API for editing docs, then write a solution in NodeJS, 2) Research how to download/upload Google docs programatically, and then edit it with a script running locally.

Comment: @JoshuaCWebDeveloper thank you for your response! For 1) are you referring to Apps Script or are you saying to look further and see if they provide something else?

Comment: I was not familiar with the Apps Script (hence why I didn't answer :) ). That is definitely the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script, If this helps..
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Thank you! That does help. I didn't realize that's what it was called; I was just assuming they were using javascript. That's what I'm using to get the info from the spreadsheet into the doc. Now I'm wondering if Apps Script is capable of deleting info.

Answer (score 1):

As you might have figured it out, that Google Apps Script has vast variety of methods and options to work with, it is almost similar to javascript.

The issue related to this scenario might not be the first one, so, App Script already provided lots of options to cover up many things.

There are built-in functions which can be executed when your sheet loads, and you can schedule the script to run at some specific time of day and/or night by using Triggers in the Script Editor interface under Edit Menu.

It depends on your logic, when the script should be executed.
Sample deleting script is as follow:

```
    function removeBlankRows(docId) {

    var document = docId ?
        DocumentApp.openById(docId) :
        DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

    var body = document.getBody();
    var search = null;
    var tables = [];

    // Extract all the tables inside the Google Document
    while (search = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE, search)) {
        tables.push(search.getElement().asTable());
    }

    tables.forEach(function (table) {
        var rows = table.getNumRows();
        // Iterate through each row of the table
        for (var r = rows - 1; r >= 0; r--) {
            // If the table row contains no text, delete it
            if (table.getRow(r).getText().replace(/s/g, "") === "") {
                table.removeRow(r);
            }
        }
    });
    document.saveAndClose();
    }
```

[removeChild](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#removeChild(Element)) method can also be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Khurram Ishaque. I was not clear in my query; I need to delete material from the google doc and not the google spreadsheet. Google docs are not quite as structured; is there a comparable command for deleting from a doc too?

Comment: thank you so much for the update! So if I'm reading this correctly, it can remove rows from tables in a document? So it will work provided I put the data that may need removed inside a table? I'm not sure if that will work for my formatting needs but I can certainly try it!! I'm up for anything! Lol it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yes. Above code will remove table rows. And other function removeChild can remove other objects from document. There is proper documentation of it.